# Is it possible to get the bottom pixel in iTextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I'm trying to design a footer, but the footer needs to be absolute on every single page.

Is there a function to grab the bottom of the page? afterward I could just subtract a few pixels and add my footer there.

```
int bottom = document.GetBottom():
ct.SetSimpleColumn(20, 20, 0, bottom - 20);
```

something along that line? Thats just pseudo code though.

Comment: funny. I just got into itextsharp last night. have you found [this](http://kuujinbo.info/iTextInAction2Ed/) yet? don't know if what your looking for is in there but it should be helpful.

Comment: Yeah that page was pretty helpful, right now I'm working on creating absolutely positioned footer.  But I'm basing it off the current document for the sake of reusability.

Answer (score 2):

the iTextSharp document provides document.Bottom which returns the bottom x value (atleast thats what worked for me)

using that I implemented a relative footer

```
PdfContentByte cb = wri.DirectContent;
ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(cb);
Phrase myText = new Phrase("footer data here", FontFactory.GetFont("Arial Bold", 10.0f, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK));
float textWidth = myText.Font.GetCalculatedBaseFont(false).GetWidthPoint("AASECT • 1444 I Street, NW • Suite 700 • Washington • DC • 20005 • (202) 449.1099 • info@aasect.org", 10.0f);
ct.SetSimpleColumn((doc.Right / 2) - (textWidth / 2), 1, (doc.Right / 2) + (textWidth / 2), doc.Bottom);

ct.AddText(myText);
ct.Go();
```

It creates the 'Phase' myText and then calculates the base font to gain access to the .GetWidthPoint to measure the size of the text.  figures out the left most x coord by calculating the center of the document and subracting half of the width and repeats the reverse for the right most x coord by adding half of the width of the text

I hope this helps somebody, I found a lot of different 'Methods' of creating a footer and none of them worked, hopefully this meets someones needs.

Comment: *I found a lot of different 'Methods' of creating a footer and none of them worked* - have you looked at the examples by itextpdf people themselves? For footers especially [MovieHistory2](https://svn.code.sf.net/p/itextsharp/code/book/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextInAction2Ed/Chapter05/MovieHistory2.cs), [MovieCountries1](https://svn.code.sf.net/p/itextsharp/code/book/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextInAction2Ed/Chapter05/MovieCountries1.cs), and [TwoPasses](https://svn.code.sf.net/p/itextsharp/code/book/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextInAction2Ed/Chapter06/TwoPasses.cs).

Comment: I did find those, but the versions I found were using 'document.footer' which is obsolete.  However I didn't get it from the itextpdf web page

Comment: *I did find those, but the versions I found were using 'document.footer' which is obsolete.* - So you *did **not** find those* I linked in my comment.

Comment: Correct, but I overlooked it when I did come across them, because I found a page with projects with the same name, and assumed they were the same.